# How to preg_replace these strings using PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a text like this `<text **** display="none">****</text> any words and htmlcodes <text **** display="none">****</text>`
 I want to remove all the string like this `<text **** display="none">****</text>`  ,begin with `<text` , end with `</text>` contain with `display="none"` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Is this well-formed XML or HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this?

```
$solution = preg_replace("@<text[^>]*display=\"none\"[^>]*>.*?</text>@ims", "", $yourstring);
```